# Correct notation when solving a double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am wondering if isolating the x-terms like I show below is correct when solving a double integral, or should I completely solve the first integral ($dy$) with the x-terms beside it before I can move to the next integral.

I know that this is correct

$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-3}^{3} \frac{xy^2}{x^2+1} \ dy \ dx = \left( \int_{0}^{1}  \frac{x}{x^2+1} \ dx \right) \left( \int_{-3}^{3} y^2 \ dy \right)
$$

but is this also correct?

$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-3}^{3} \frac{xy^2}{x^2+1} \ dy \ dx = \int_{0}^{1} \left[ \left( \frac{x}{x^2+1} \right) \int_{-3}^{3} y^2 \ dy \right] \ dx = \cdots
$$

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, both are correct (in fact, I'd say the second form is just an intermediate step to get the final one in the first notation).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I worked out the integration and all three turn out as $9\ln 2$.

However, do not think about applying this to double integrals in general.